# Trouble with while to make a loop

Tags: java, android, while-loop

```
    cameraOn();
    while (counter == 1){
        if(counter == 0){
             cameraOn();
             counter += 1;
         }else{
            cameraOff();
            counter -= 1;
          }
    }
```

The methods are:

```
private void cameraOff() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
             camera.setParameters(parameters);
             camera.release();
             camera = null;
        }

        private void cameraOn() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera = Camera.open();
             parameters = camera.getParameters();
             parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
             camera.setParameters(parameters);
        }
```

and I have a button who have to break the loop and finish the activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (camera == null){
        finish();
    }else{
         parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
         camera.setParameters(parameters);
         camera.release();
         camera = null;
         finish();
    }
```

I'm a beginner and I don't understand how does the loop work, I tought with the counter I could do it, but it didn't work.
What I'm trying is to make the camera flash blink every second in a loop until I will press the button. please help me. Thanks

Comment: What do you want the loop to do?

Comment: well for starters, the first part of the if statement will never be executed because counter can never be equal to 0 at the beginning of an iteration.

Comment: Where is counter and camera initiatied?

Comment: I'm trying to make the flash camera blink every second in a loop until I will press the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, entering a loop only when counter == 0 means it will never enter the inner loop requiring counter == 1, and never enter cameraOn().

Try this:

Clear out your onClick method and replace it with:

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) {
    cameraOff();
    /* or 'toggle();' if you prefer, see below */
}
```

(Since it appears to do exactly the same things.)

Comment out / delete that whole nested loop, and be sure to call cameraOn() or toggle() somewhere to get things started.

For setting up the toggle, you can add a `static Boolean isFlashActive;` (or otherwise detect the flash state, I haven't used that api yet)

..and add a function:

```
private toggle(){
    if ( isFlashActive ) {
        cameraOff();
    } else {
        cameraOn();
    }
    /* delay? */
}
```

For the toggle delay, you have a couple options:

First, you can call toggle() from another thread via a `Runnable` or one of the android options like `AsyncTask` while adding a wait() into the toggle function to provide the delay;

Second is my personal favorite, which is to setup an intent receiver then use `setRepeating()` with a `PendingIntent`.

Comment: But I need to do a loop, for switch on/off all the time not only when the button is press it. I need  the flash will be blinking

Comment: edited .. for some reason I saw "flash" in your sample and thought it was a custom method instead of the camera flash lol. Will have a look at the api and post some code for you.

Answer (score 2):

if (counter == 0) will never be true as your loop will exit in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The following part of your code will never be executed because you only enter the while block if counter == 1.

```
 if(counter == 0){
            cameraOn();
            counter += 1;
```

So if you ever entered your while block `while (counter == 1)`, you will always end up calling cameraOff() method. In other words your if statement will never be true and the else statement will be the one to be always executed.